# Highlight in yellow a word in a string (sentence)

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I create a small word document from excel in vba. I would like to highlight in yellow a word in a sentence. Currently, it is what I am doing:

```
        wdDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Last.Range.Characters(60).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorYellow
```

...which is good for one character, but not great for several characters. In my case, I am highlighted a word of 7 characters which is feasible by repeating this line above and changing the index.

But, I am curious and would like to know if there is a better way to do it.
Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at the MoveEnd method of the Word Range object.

Comment: Instead of the Characters collection, set the bounds of the Range. Something like `.Range(Start:=60, End:=66).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColoryYellow`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, I actually try that before and I tried again now, but still with an error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this little snippet. It determines the position of the 60th character of the past paragraph within the document and then sets a range starting from there.

```
Dim wdDoc As Document
Dim p As Long

Set wdDoc = ActiveDocument
p = wdDoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range.Characters(60).Start
wdDoc.Range(p, p + 7).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorYellow
```

There should be an easier way to do this but I didn't find it.

Comment: Works well for me, and certainly better of what I did! I think the method of RonRosenfeld should work as well, but I was not able to position it correctly to highlight what I wanted. Probably using the MoveEnd method (or Move) will work, but the examples I found online were not helpful. Anyway, I like this one as it is easy to use. Thanks.